# Not Creating Table with PDO

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I have a sql command that I am trying to execute using PDO and it executes true, but the table is not created. I have no idea what I am doing wrong. I looked around the internet to see if anyone else has had this problem, but I didnt really seem to find anything that fixes it. Here is the SQL Command

```
CREATE TABLE table_230
(
    id VARCHAR(255),
    cost VARCHAR(255),
    title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    package_quantity VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    package_cost VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    asin VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    rank VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
    category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    bb_price VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    seller_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    size_tier VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    amazon_fee VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    roi VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    parent_asin VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    complete TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0
)
```

The command runs in PHPMyAdmin when I attempt to execute it, but it does not work when I use PDO. The code that I use looks like this:

```
$create = $this->dbConnection->prepare("
        CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_" . $tableId ."
        (
            id VARCHAR(255),
            cost VARCHAR(255),
            title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            package_quantity VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            package_cost VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            asin VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
            rank VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
            category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            bb_price VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            seller_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            size_tier VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            amazon_fee VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            roi VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            parent_asin VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
            complete TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0
        )");
if($create->execute() === true)
{
    return true;
}
```

It always returns true. If someone could help me out, I would really appreciate it!

Comment: `varchar` for everything? That's never a good sign...

Comment: Are you sure you're creating it in the right database? Also testing that something is super literally true is usually redundant.

Comment: It's also highly worrying that you're creating so many of these tables. That's usually a sign that your database normalization needs some work.

Comment: I am creating a table for each upload that I process. Varchar is not needed for everything, but I am using it for testing since I am not really good with SQL.

Comment: Are you sure `$tableId` contains what you expect?

Comment: Try echoing the SQL to see if it's what you intended?

Comment: It contains the data from the last inserted id. The command is what I expected. The execute returns true, but the table is not being created. When I use the exact command that PDO is using in phpmyadmin, it creates the table. Otherwise it is false.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set up your connection first:

```
$mysql_host = "servername";
$mysql_database = "dbname";
$mysql_user = "username";
$mysql_password = "pass";


try{
$conn = new PDO(
"mysql:dbname=" .   $mysql_database .
";host=" .          $mysql_host     . 
";charset=utf8"         ,
$mysql_user             ,  
$mysql_password         , 
array(                  //
    PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
    PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_INIT_COMMAND => "SET NAMES utf8"
    )
);

}catch(PDOException $e){
echo $e->getCode();

}
```

Then query:

```
$tableId=$conn->lastInsertId();
$create = $conn->prepare("
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS table_" . $tableId ."
    (
        id VARCHAR(255),
        cost VARCHAR(255),
        title VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        package_quantity VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        package_cost VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        asin VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
        rank VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL,
        category VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        bb_price VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        seller_type VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        size_tier VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        amazon_fee VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        roi VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        parent_asin VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
        complete TINYINT(1) DEFAULT 0
    )");
if($create->execute() === true)
{
return true;
}
```

This code works. Are you sure your $tableId variable is having expected value? you should var_dump($tableId) to see what's in it!